# Give Rectangle an id

Tags: javascript, canvas

http://fiddle.jshell.net/f6rLds4g/6/

Is it possible to give the rectangle that i make an id ?

What I whant is , that when i click on a rectangle that it shows data in the next canvas

So instead of rectangle 0 clicked it must show data (from json or xml of database) but before i can make that , it should have id (I think)

```
  var canvas = $('#NodeList').get(0);
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.height = 0;

var a = 20;
var x = 150;
var y = 100;


var rects = [
    [a, 20, x, y],
    [a, 220, x, y],
    [a, 420, x, y],
    [a, 620, x, y],
    [a, 820, x, y],
    [a, 1020, x, y],
    [a, 1220, x, y],
    [a, 1420, x, y],
    [a, 1620, x, y],
    [a, 1820, x, y]



];
for (var i = 0; i < rects.length; i++) {
    canvas.height = canvas.height + 200;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    //rectangles opnieuw tekenen
    for (var j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        ctx.fillRect(rects[j][0],
        rects[j][1],
        rects[j][2],
        rects[j][3]);
    }
    ctx.fillRect(rects[i][0],
    rects[i][1],
    rects[i][2],
    rects[i][3]);

}

$('#NodeList').click(function (e) {
    var x = e.offsetX,
        y = e.offsetY;



        for (var i = 0; i < rects.length; i++) {
    if (x > rects[i][0] && x < rects[i][0] + rects[i][2] && y > rects[i][1] && y < rects[i][1] + rects[i][3]) {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("NodeDisplay");
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        context.fillText('Rectangle ' + i + ' clicked', 110, 10);
    }
}



});
```

For the whole html page click on the link at the beginning

Comment: A rectangle on a canvas is not an object any more, it is just a "loose" and unrelated collection of colored pixels. If you want to use objects on canvas I would suggest you use frameworks like processing.js, kineticjs or raphael

Answer (score 1):

You can assign ids only to elements.
Since your rectangle is not an element, but the content of a canvas, it cannot have an id.

However, there are three ways to work around this that come to my mind:

1. Assign a `click` event listener to your canvas and check with JavaScript whether the clicked coordinates are inside a rectangle or not.
2. Use HTML elements instead of drawing rectangles on a canvas. An element with a fixed width, height, `display: block` and `position: absolute` will appear exactly the same, but being an HTML element, it can have an id.
3. Draw whatever you want on your canvas and put a [`map`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp) tag with clickable areas over your it. This way you have precise control over the color value and clickability of every single pixel, but the code might get lengthy and it is probably a bit overkill for just rectangles.

Comment: Is it possible to do step 2 in a canvas ???
i am a beginner at this and the question is how do i make. Should i start over ??  Or can i use the script that i already have

Comment: @S.Oruc It is not. The reason for this is that `canvas` is meant to different from the DOM. It is just a canvas you draw to. Your rectangle is not an element, but a rectangular splat of color in a bitmap. Much like it would be in MSPaint. Libraries such as KineticJS which allow these events handle it the way @Siguza describes in his first suggestion. It's an abstraction over the objects you pass to KineticJS, not some browser API that treats your draws as separate elements, because there is no such thing.

Comment: @S.Oruc Think of your canvas as an image. From HTML's point of view, it's basically an image.

Answer (score 1):

You are saving your rects in an array: `var rects=[]`.

You are representing each rect as an array containing x,y,width,height.

So if you want to give each rect an id, simply add an id to each rect's array:

```
var rects = [
    [a, 20, x, y, 'rect0'],
    [a, 220, x, y, 'rect1'],
    [a, 420, x, y, 'rect2'],
    [a, 620, x, y, 'rect3'],
    [a, 820, x, y, 'rect4'],
    [a, 1020, x, y, 'rect5'],
    [a, 1220, x, y, 'rect6'],
    [a, 1420, x, y, 'rect7'],
    [a, 1620, x, y, 'rect8'],
    [a, 1820, x, y, 'rect9']
];
```

Then you can access the id element of the rect array when needed:

```
// test if this is rect with id=='rect3'
var n=3;
if(rects[n][4]=='rect3'){ alert('I have the id==rect3'); }
```

Comment: If i try it , it gives prompt when I open the page. (without me clicking  a rectangle)